conda environment created as osx-64, now cannot use VSCode (Failed to start the Kernel)
I created a conda environment in Terminal like so:
conda create -n hello python=3.8
conda activate hello
conda config --env --set subdir osx-64

Then installed a bunch of packages. I am on a M2 mac but some packages I need are not available for M1/M2 macs, hence --set subdir osx-64. After a few trials, I could finally install everything I need.
Problem is, I now cannot use run Jupyter notebook in VSCode within that conda environment! I have a suspicion it is because of the odd conda environment as it constantly says:

Failed to start the Kernel.
...
(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
...

Can you help?

Ah, I know what I did wrong! I installed python, before changing the conda environment to osx-64.
The following works:
# first delete the environment
conda deactivate
conda remove --name deepprime --all

# then to create it again properly
conda create -n hello
conda activate hello
conda config --env --set subdir osx-64
conda install python=3.8
# etc.

And now Jupyter/VSCode is happy.
